# What does "life's a beach" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Somewhere on Yahoo News I read this text:

> Scarlett Johansson and Sean Penn
>   turned heads when they showed up
>   together at Reese Witherspoon's
>   wedding. The 26-year-old actress took
>   50-year-old Penn, who is 24 years her
>   senior, as her date to the
>   star-studded nuptials. Plus, Lady Gaga
>   sets a new Twitter record, and **life's
>   a beach** for David Beckham and Sofia
>   Vergara as they shoot a Diet Pepsi
>   commercial.

What does "life's a beach" mean?

Comment: They totally forgot to mention that Penn is 24 years older than Johansson, and that they are 24 years apart. (Also, their age difference is 24 years, but that's a different story altogether.)

Comment: The link no longer points to the quoted text.

Comment: @RegDwighт Wow, 50 - 26 *is* 24. That you need to say it twice says something about the target audience. (We might want to vet the number sentences with math.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a riff on the phrase "life's a bitch" (meaning life can be difficult and unpleasant) which turns it around into a positive. "Life's a beach" means that, at that moment at least, life was nothing but wonderful for David Beckham and Sofia Vergara. Think about beaches: sun, sand, water, beautiful people in bathing suits ... you get the idea.

Comment: Aaaah! Thank you. For some reason I thought that "*Lady Gaga*" here was a subject and "*life's a beach*" was a predicate, hence, my puzzlement (because I knew that the word "*life*" was not a verb). Now it's clear: "*life*" is the subject and "*'s a beach*" is the predicate, and Lady Gaga has no business here - it's another sentence. Thanks again.

Comment: @brilliant: "Lady Gaga has no business here"...exactly!

Comment: It should also be noted that the commercial in question literally takes place on a beach.  ([YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B79RkBxSgU).)

Answer (score 4):

It means something positive. Almost like "Life is Good".  Who doesn't like a Beach? The beach makes you relaxed, feel warm, have fun in the water, enjoy life.  "Life's a Beach" denotes that life is good or great.  The phrase was invented to counteract the negative phrase of "Life's a bitch".